Find direction to coordinates relative to 0, 0
I have a 10x10 grid, in which in this case is my 'table'. I have two positions on this board: X, and Y.
X is positioned at 5, 5, whilst Y is positioned at 0, 0. Each letter also has a secondary value, their direction, which is currently set at 90 degrees. How would I manage to have Y's direction face towards X's position?

If I understood you correctly, the plot of the positions should look like this:

We can use these points to draw a right-angled triangle adjacent to the horizontal axis:

Now, in order to make Y face the direction of X, we need to figure out the value of the angle at the point Y. Since it's apparent that the short sides of the triangle are both $5$ units long, we can use the $\arctan$ function to find the angle at Y based on the ratio of the sides opposite and adjacent to the angle.
$\arctan\left(\frac55\right)=45^\circ$
This means that in order for Y to be facing X, it should be angled $45^\circ$ up from the horizontal axis.
